# Why is it a good idea to use Math.min() for x, y coordinates and math.abs()

Tags: java

Why is it a good idea to use `Math.min()` for x-y coordinates and width and height using `Math.abs()` method (for Rectangle)? I thought the x-y coordinates were always positive, so I'm confused to why it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The x,y coordinates represent the position of the rectangle on a plane; they can be negative since the rectangle can be place anywhere relative to the origin (ie. 0,0 position).

The height and width of the rectangle must be positive as negative lenghts are really not defined.

Considering this then, it makes sense to use `Math.min` for position and `Math.abs` for dimension.

Comment: That's what I thought, I just didn't know that they could be negative. Thanks!